# Nested List doesn't update after delete

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I sort of have 2 questions here, firstly, with the approach I have attempted, where is my error?

Secondly, is this the best approach (I was hoping for a cleaner way using list comprehension, but I couldn't figure it out due to the nesting).

So in essence, the function below compares 2 lists, they may not be the same size (new_order_books would normally be smaller).

What I wanted to do is effectively join the 2 lists, however the structure is as follows for both new and old _order_books:

order_books -> order_book -> orders -> order (order.market_id, order.size_matched, order.cancelled, order....)

I can't change the way I receive the data and all new orders come via new_order_book (old_order_book should remain static).

However, when I try a simple extend, because both order_books may have orders from the same market (order_book) this means I end up with duplicates (as lets say 2 new orders have come in, when I try old_order_books.extend(new_order_books) I then see all the old orders x 2 plus the 2 new ones.

Hence I wanted to delete any order_book within old_order_books where the market_id is the same as a market_id within an order_book in new_order_books (each order_book is a separate market_id).

My plan was then, having deleted that order_book, to insert the newer version into old_order_books from new_order_books and return this as an updated version with all up-to-date orders.

However this doesn't appear to work, I still get the duplicates so it seems as though when I delete the order_book within the loop, when I look at the list outside the loop no change has occurred.

The final step, was once, I have deleted the orders from a particular order_book, to delete that order_book completely, however given the orders don't seem to delete, this step is currently redundant.

Hopefully that explains it clearly enough, but I will try to clarify anything.

I also suspect, that there is a better way to attempt this, but I couldn't figure out the logic, so please feel free to suggest a plan B, rather than this approach!

For the avoidance of doubt (it may not be relevant) order_book, order etc. are custom classes, hence the syntax order.market_id etc. is correct.

```
def compare_current_orders(old_order_books, new_order_books):
    temp_old_market_id_list = []
    for order_book in old_order_books:
        for order in order_book.orders:
            temp_old_market_id_list.append(order.market_id)

    temp_new_market_id_list = []
    for order_book in new_order_books:
        for order in order_book.orders:
            temp_new_market_id_list.append(order.market_id)

    market_id_list = set(temp_new_market_id_list).intersection(temp_new_market_id_list)

    for order_book in old_order_books:
        for order in order_book.orders:
            if order.market_id in market_id_list:
                del order
                break

    for order_book in old_order_books:
        for order in order_book.orders:
            print(order.size_remaining, order.size_cancelled)

    old_order_books2 = list(filter(None, old_order_books))
    old_order_books2.extend(new_order_books)

    return old_order_books2
```

Comment: You obviously can't replicate the problem @Prune, this code snippet is just a single function, but please let me know which part is unclear and I'll do my best to clarify, I did try to include everything I could think of, but apologies if its unclear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, you don't seem to understand this site. If you want us to tell you what is wrong with your code, you need to give us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are glad to help but we do have some requirements to make our work easier and for other reasons. For example, you may discover the problem yourself when you make a MCVE. Read the link and do your best, then post that code in your question.

Comment: One thing your code is doing wrong is modifying (deleting) items in the list that's being iterated-over — which usually doesn't work. You also don't seem to understand the _minimal_ aspect of providing a example code that illustrates & reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "cleaned" list is the same as the original, because you have no code that alters the main list.  It appears that you expect this to do the job.

```
for order_book in old_order_books:
    for order in order_book.orders:
        if order.market_id in market_id_list:
            del order
            break
```

`order` is a local variable that iterates through the orders in `order_book`; it is *not* linked to `order_book`.  Your command `del order` very pointedly does not affect `order_book`; all it does is to destroy the variable `order`.

I recommend that you work through a tutorial on filtering a sequence, including list comprehensions.  You can make a new list to your specifications with something like

```
new_list = [order for order in order_book.orders
               if order.market_id not in market_id_list]
```

This returns a list of the items you appear to want to keep.

Comment: Thank you @Prune, that does make sense, but you have highlighted the problem I face and cant' work through. There is no tutorial on complex list comprehensions unfortunately and I haven't been able to work out the syntax. In essence your solution, is one level short. As order_book.orders is within the order_books object, so I need to iterate through that too and I can't work out how to do another level of iterating within the list comprehension! I get your logic on the delete point, so I agree your approach makes sense, but it won't work in its current form :-(

Comment: Yes, you still have to iterate through old_order_books, because you're dealing with each of its elements individually.  You can't replace everything with a single line, because you need individual results for each `.orders` entry.

Comment: Ah thank you, that was what I was missing, was hoping it would be possible purely with list comprehension, but that I simply wasn't getting it. If I need to iterate through the first level, then perform the list comprehension I can re-try like that. Much appreciated!